# Does https affect adsense?

Tags: google, https, google-adsense

I am starting a new guest blog where I write posts and ask others to write as well.

I will be using adsense with my website very soon and I want to know if the SSL I'm using will affect the performance of the ads.

Also if it is going to affect it, is it better to https with login and submission screens only or it wont make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. It affects adsense big time.

Google does not make SSL compliancy mandatory for Adwords and third party ad networks.

HTTPS-enabled sites require that all content on the page, including the ads, be SSL-compliant. As such, AdSense will remove all non-SSL compliant ads from competing in the auction on these pages.

If you do decide to convert your HTTP site to HTTPS be aware that ads on your HTTPS pages might earn less than those on your HTTP pages.

Comment: Do I have to resubmit my website for review when converting from HTTPS to HTTP? Also what steps do I need to take in order to make the conversion smooth? I will contact the support of the host for sure but sometimes they forget stuff, so i want to make sure that I know what I want to ask them to do.